# How to compile *.lua files as resource library?

Tags: lua

In original, I collect *.lua files in a folder , then load them in *.c files

Now I want to hide them(*.lua) and let them in a xx.so or xx.dll

if this can be done ?

if can , then how to load them in c files ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171929/how-to-embed-a-lua-script-within-a-c-binary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use Lua if you've got code to hide (as it's always possible to decompile it), but you could simply do the following:

- Compile the script files using `luac`. This will give you output files with precompiled object code (not machine code) in them. (This step is optional but it makes it harder to read/find the actual code in the compiled file.)
- Write a simply tool to read those files putting them into character arrays.

The resulting code should look a bit like this:

```
const char firstlua_lua[] = {0x11,0x12,0x13,0x14,...};
```

It will use the actual bytes found in the compile lua script obviously.
You'll then be able to simply run these "strings" like any script source loaded.