# Embedding Lua in C application in Visual Studio 2008 or 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, lua

I am developing a network application in ANSI C.
I would like to use Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 to develop it.
I want to embed Lua as a scripting language.

I would like suggestions as to whether or not I should compile the
application with Lua's sourcecode, or if I should use a .dll.

If I should compile with the source, how would I go about doing that?
If I should compile with a .dll, how would that work?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171929/how-to-embed-a-lua-script-within-a-c-binary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go down either route.   Pretty simple to compile into your code though, just include all the source  ( except, you don't need the stuff for the Lua command line tool).   Once you've done this, you have access to the API, and away you go!